# How to add Payment method title in order email

Tags: email, magento

I have added one Transactional Email for new order in admin. And i want to insert new variable for magento payment method in the bottom of my order email. But i'm not getting how i can achieve this. Can someone help me to solve this?

There is already code for Payment method block `{{var payment_html}}`

But i want to add only title of Payment method in footer of order email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}` should print out the title.

Comment: Can you share for Magento 2.4 versions?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the template;
which you can do here:
System > Templates > Transactional Emails

For more information you can look this up:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails